# Splitting article by sentences using delimiters

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a small assignment where I have an article in a format that is like this

```
<REUTERS TOPICS="NO" LEWISSPLIT="TRAIN" CGISPLIT="TRAINING-SET" OLDID="5545" NEWID="2">
<TITLE>STANDARD OIL &lt;SRD> TO FORM FINANCIAL UNIT</TITLE>
<DATELINE>    CLEVELAND, Feb 26 - </DATELINE><BODY>Standard Oil Co and BP North America
Inc said they plan to form a venture to manage the money market
borrowing and investment activities of both companies.
BP North America is a subsidiary of British Petroleum Co
Plc &lt;BP>, which also owns a 55 pct interest in Standard Oil.
The venture will be called BP/Standard Financial Trading
and will be operated by Standard Oil under the oversight of a
joint management committee.

Reuter
&#3;</BODY></TEXT>
</REUTERS>
```

and I am writing it to a new xml file with this format

```
<article id= some id >
      <subject>articles subject </subject>
      <sentence> sentence #1 </sentence>
      .
      .
      .
      <sentence> sentence #n </sentence>
 </article>
```

I have written a code that does all of this and works fine.

The problem is that I am splitting sentences by using the delimiter `.`, but if the there is a number like 2.00, the code thinks that 2 is a sentence and 00 is a different sentence.

Does anyone have any idea on how to identify sentences better so it will keep the numbers and such in same sentence?

Without having to go over all of the array?

Is there a way I can have the `string.Split()` method ignore the split if there is a number before and after the delimiter?

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Data; 
using System.Xml;
namespace project
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"path");
            string body = "";
            REUTERS article = new REUTERS();
            string sentences = "";
            for (int i = 0; i<lines.Length;i++){
                string line = lines[i];
                // finding the first tag of the article
                if (line.Contains("<REUTERS"))
                {
                    //extracting the id from the tag
                    int Id = line.IndexOf("NEWID=\"") + "NEWID=\"".Length;
                    article.NEWID = line.Substring(Id, line.Length-2 - Id); 
                }
                if (line.Contains("TITLE"))
                {
                    string subject = line;
                    subject = subject.Replace("<TITLE>", "").Replace("</TITLE>", "");

                    article.TITLE = subject;
                }
                if( line.Contains("<BODY"))
                {
                    int startLoc = line.IndexOf("<BODY>") + "<BODY>".Length;
                    sentences = line.Substring(startLoc, line.Length - startLoc);    
                    while (!line.Contains("</BODY>"))
                    {
                        i++;
                        line = lines[i];
                        sentences = sentences +" " + line;
                    }
                    int endLoc = sentences.IndexOf("</BODY>");
                    sentences = sentences.Substring(0, endLoc);
                    char[] delim = {'.'};
                    string[] sentencesSplit = sentences.Split(delim);

                    using (System.IO.StreamWriter file =
                       new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"path",true))
                    {
                        file.WriteLine("<articles>");
                        file.WriteLine("\t <article id = " + article.NEWID + ">");
                        file.WriteLine("\t \t <subject>" + article.TITLE + "</subject>");

                        foreach (string sentence in sentencesSplit)
                        {
                            file.WriteLine("\t \t <sentence>" + sentence + "</sentence>");
                        }
                        file.WriteLine("\t </article>");
                        file.WriteLine("</articles>");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public class REUTERS
        {
            public string NEWID;
            public string TITLE;
            public string Body;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: split by `". "` dot then space since most sentences have a white space after the full stop. you could include line breaks as well. this seems like something for regex.

Comment: the method split though recives a char[] so i cant do a ". " since it is a string not a char

Comment: use `". ".ToCharArray()` then.

Comment: that would still create a char array with to elements the . dot and the space and would split by both of these so it wont solve the problem

Comment: @YuvalHaran as you eventually realized Split can take string array as well.

Comment: What about `John F. Cookie` or `U.S.S.B` or `my.site.com` or `my.email@Cookies.net` or many other uses of `.`?

Answer (score 0):

ok so i found a solution using the ideas i recieved here
i used the overload method of split like this

```
.Split(new string[] { ". " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

and it looks much better now

Comment: If this works for you, something is wrong with your question. In your question, the dots that end sentences aren't followed by a space. This seems unreliable anyway, since a period that isn't followed by a space may still end a sentence, for example if it is followed by a closing quotation mark and then a space.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a regular expression that looks for the sentence terminators with white space:

```
var pattern = @"(?<=[\.!\?])\s+";
var sentences = Regex.Split(input, pattern);

foreach (var sentence in sentences) {
    //do something with the sentence
    var node = string.Format("\t \t <sentence>{0}</sentence>", sentence);
    file.WriteLine(node);
}
```

Note that this applies to the English language as there may be other rules for sentences in other languages.

The Following example

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var input = @"Standard Oil Co and BP North America
Inc said they plan to form a venture to manage the money market
borrowing and investment activities of both companies.
BP North America is a subsidiary of British Petroleum Co
Plc <BP>, which also owns a 55 pct interest in Standard Oil.
The venture will be called BP/Standard Financial Trading
and will be operated by Standard Oil under the oversight of a
joint management committee.";
        var pattern = @"(?<=[\.!\?])\s+";
        var sentences = Regex.Split(input, pattern);
        foreach (var sentence in sentences)
        {
            var innerText = sentence.Replace("\n", " ").Replace('\t', ' ');
            //do something with the sentence
            var node = string.Format("\t \t <sentence>{0}</sentence>", innerText);
            Console.WriteLine(node);
        }
    }
}
```

Produces this output

```xml
      <sentence>Standard Oil Co and BP North America Inc said they plan to form a venture to manage the money market borrowing and investment activities of both companies.</sentence>
      <sentence>BP North America is a subsidiary of British Petroleum Co Plc <BP>, which also owns a 55 pct interest in Standard Oil.</sentence>
      <sentence>The venture will be called BP/Standard Financial Trading and will be operated by Standard Oil under the oversight of a joint management committee.</sentence>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make a list of all index points of the '.' characters.

foreach index point, check each side for numbers, if numbers are on both sides, remove the index point from the list.

Then when you are outputting simply use the substring functions with the remaining index points to get each sentence as an individual.

Bad quality code follows (it's late):

```
List<int> indexesToRemove = new List<int>();
int count=0;
foreach(int indexPoint in IndexPoints)
{
    if((sentence.elementAt(indexPoint-1)>='0' && elementAt(indexPoint-1<='9')) && (sentence.elementAt(indexPoint+1)>='0' && elementAt(indexPoint+1<='9')))
        indexesToRemove.Add(count);
    count++;
}
```

The next line is so that we do not have to alter the removal number as we traverse the list in the last step.

```
indexesToRemove = indexesToRemove.OrderByDescending();
```

Now we simply remove all the locations of the '.'s that have numbers on either side.

```
foreach(int indexPoint in indexesToRemove)
{
    IndexPoints.RemoveAt(indexPoint);
}
```

Now when you read out the sentences into the new file format you just loop `sentences.substring(lastIndexPoint+1, currentIndexPoint)`

Answer (score 0):

Spent much time on this - thought you might like to see it as it really doesn't use any awkward code whatsoever - it is producing output 99% similar to yours.

```
<articles>
    <article id="2">
        <subject>STANDARD OIL &lt;SRD&gt; TO FORM FINANCIAL UNIT</subject>
        <sentence>Standard Oil Co and BP North America</sentence>
        <sentence>Inc said they plan to form a venture to manage the money market</sentence>
        <sentence>borrowing and investment activities of both companies.</sentence>
        <sentence>BP North America is a subsidiary of British Petroleum Co</sentence>
        <sentence>Plc &lt;BP&gt;, which also owns a 55.0 pct interest in Standard Oil.</sentence>
        <sentence>The venture will be called BP/Standard Financial Trading</sentence>
        <sentence>and will be operated by Standard Oil under the oversight of a</sentence>
        <sentence>joint management committee.</sentence>
    </article>
</articles>
```

The console app is as follows:

```
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;

namespace ReutersXML
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

            xmlDoc.Load("reuters.xml");

            var reuters = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("REUTERS");
            var article = reuters[0].Attributes.GetNamedItem("NEWID").Value;
            var subject = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].InnerText;
            var body = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].InnerText;

            string[] sentences = body.Split(new string[] { System.Environment.NewLine },
                System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("reuters_new.xml", FileMode.Create))
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
            using (XmlTextWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(sw))
            {
                xmlWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                xmlWriter.Indentation = 4;

                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("articles");
                xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("article");
                xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("id", article);
                xmlWriter.WriteElementString("subject", subject);

                foreach (var s in sentences)
                    if (s.Length > 10)
                        xmlWriter.WriteElementString("sentence", s);

                xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope you like it :)